# Incorrect Python Interpreter in Base Conda Environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, path, anaconda, conda

I have run into this problem where I try to run a python script that uses the pandas module in my base anaconda3 environment but I get an errror: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. I thought this was strange, because the (base) conda environment is supposed to come with the pandas module pre-installed. I know the conda environment is activated, because when I start up my Z shell terminal I get the following outputs:

```
source /Users/(my profile name)/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) (my name)-MBP ~ % source /Users/(my profile name)/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) (my name)-MBP ~ % conda activate base
```

To test to see what was going on, I ran the following code in a separate script:

```
import sys

print('python: {}'.format(sys.version))
from shutil import which
print(which('python'))
```

which outputted:

```
python: 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:53) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
/usr/bin/python
```

But when I run `conda list` the python version is 3.9.7. As a final check I typed `echo $PATH` on the command line and this is what it returned

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/(my profile name)/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/(my profile name)/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
```

For context I am running the terminal in Visual Studio Code.
Any help?

Comment: Why is `source <env_path>/activate` being used? The canonical activation command has been `conda activate <env_name>` since Conda v4.4.

Comment: That command got used automatically when I started the terminal on VS Code.

Comment: Probably better to tag VSCode then, and try searching for Conda-VSCode terminal issues.